# How to unit test a single conversational statement

Tags: unit-testing, testing, botframework, bots, azure-qna-maker

i am working with bots and the Microsoft Bot Framework.
I used the DispatchBot template to generate my bot. (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs)

For conversational testing, i want to create unit tests. Therefore i used this documentation to gather some informations (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/unit-test-bots?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

[image]

The thing is that i dont want to test dialogs, but a single statement (a question and the right answer)
How can i implement this?

[image]

Here you can see the Start of my Dispatchbot.cs file where the magic happens (search of the correct Knowledge Base etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a link to how we create tests for CoreBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot.tests). The part you're most likely interested in is [testing things under the `/Bots` directory](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot.tests/Bots). Based off of the test code you can find there, you likely want something like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CoreBot.Tests.Common;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Adapters;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace KJCBOT_Tests
{
    public class BotTests 
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestResponseToQuesion()
        {
            // Note: this test requires that SaveChangesAsync is made virtual in order to be able to create a mock.
            var memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
            var mockConversationState = new Mock<ConversationState>(memoryStorage)
            {
                CallBase = true,
            };

            var mockUserState = new Mock<UserState>(memoryStorage)
            {
                CallBase = true,
            };

            // You need to mock a dialog because most bots require a Dialog to instantiate it.
            // If yours doesn't you can likely skip this
            var mockRootDialog = SimpleMockFactory.CreateMockDialog<Dialog>(null, "mockRootDialog");
            var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<DispatchBot<Dialog>>>();

            // Act
            var sut = new DispatchBot<Dialog>(mockConversationState.Object, mockUserState.Object, mockRootDialog.Object, mockLogger.Object);
            var testAdapter = new TestAdapter();
            var testFlow = new TestFlow(testAdapter, sut);
            await testFlow
                    .Send("<Whatever you want to send>")
                    .AssertReply("<Whatever you expect the reply to be")
                    .StartTestAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am still relatively new to the whole topic of programming. I get the error "The type or namespace name 'DialogBot<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" when implementing your code. I have added a screenshot to the question of me at the bottom. It shows the beginning of my Bots/Dispatchbot.cs file. Does this help a little bit with fixing my problem?

Comment: `<DialogBot>` is going to change based on what your bot is called. Looks like it's `DispatchBot`, so you can try switching to that. The code example I gave you was from CoreBot. Since your bot is different, you'll likely need to switch some things around to match yours.